# Unable to display the object, which i retrieved from the other component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and redux, it is creating an object in console. When I inspect in `sentitem` Component, it is showing the respective object.

I was new to redux... could you please help me in this?

Unable to display the object in page

Comment: Hi Chandan, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` will print the data in `console`, but not on the page,

```
<Grid.Column width={12}>
   sentMessage {console.log(this.props.sentMessage)}
</Grid.Column>
```

You can iterate over the `sentMessage` array,

```
<Grid.Column width={12}>
   sentMessage {this.props.sentMessage.map(msg => <>
      {Object.keys(msg).map(key => 
          <div>{msg[key]}</div>
      )}
   </>)}
</Grid.Column>
```

Another issue is, in your reducer by doing this,

```
state.sentMessage.concat([action.payload])
```

You are actually concating the array in array, you just need to do this,

```
return {
   ...state,
   sentMessage: state.sentMessage.concat(action.payload)  //concat te object in array which create's array of object
}
```

---

**Update**

As you want to display something like this on your page,

```
{"To":"this.state.to","Cc":"this.state.cc","Bcc":"this.state.bcc","Subject":"this.state.subject"}
```

You can do this,

```
<Grid.Column width={12}>
   sentMessage {this.props.sentMessage.map(msg => JSON.stringify(msg) )}   //This will print the object on page
</Grid.Column>
```

[Simplified Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8yssxe)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199233/discussion-on-answer-by-ravibagul91-unable-to-display-the-object-which-i-retrie).

Comment: @ravibagul91 I already went through that but not sure how i can use this in my case?          I've gone through this link, here there is only one input and they represented in a reducer but i have 3-4 inputs, then how can i assign that states to those inputs in reducer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571794/pass-data-between-independent-component-react-and-redux

Comment: In you case it might be `this.props.dispatch({
       type:'SENT_MESSAGE',
       payload: sentMessage});`

Comment: The issue is, by looking at codebase I cannot tell where you gone wrong, if you can create a codepen or sandboxcode then I can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentMessage: state.sentMessage.concat([action.payload])
```

This should be

```
sentMessage: state.sentMessage.concat(action.payload)
(or)
sentMessage: [ ...state.sentMessage, action.payload]
```