# how to convert the following code into managing code

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to redux, dont know where i'm going wrong. Do i need change the whole code into props? if i have to change the respective code into props then how to take those inputs which i've taken states {}? Could you please help me on this?

I have gone through this link "[Pass data between independent component react and redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571794/pass-data-between-independent-component-react-and-redux)" but it have only one input and here i have multiple components.

First Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Icon, Modal, Form} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import './Email.css'
//import Editor from './Edit'
import * as storeActions from "../redux/storeActions";

class Compose extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    to: "",
    cc: "",
    bcc: "",
    subject: ""
  }
  this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the values from state
    const To = this.state.to;
    const Cc =  this.state.cc;
    const Bcc =  this.state.bcc;
    const Subject = this.state.subject;

    const sentItem = {
      To,
      Cc,
      Bcc,
      Subject
    }
    // this.props.dispatch({
    //   type:'SENT_MESSAGE',
    //   sentMessage});
console.log(sentItem)
 }

changeHandler = (e) => {
  this.props.dispatch({
    type: 'SENT_MESSAGE',
    payload: e.target.value
});
}
    render() {
      return (
        <Modal trigger={<Button animated inverted color='blue'>
          <Button.Content visible>Compose</Button.Content>
          <Button.Content hidden>
            <Icon name='plus'/>
          </Button.Content>
        </Button>} closeIcon>

           <Modal.Content>
             <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<Form.Input fluid label='To' type="text" className='txtBox' name="to" value={this.state.to} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
<Form.Input fluid label='Cc' type="text" className='txtBox' name="cc"value={this.state.cc} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
<Form.Input fluid label='Bcc' type="text" className='txtBox'name="bcc"value={this.state.bcc} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
<Form.Input fluid label='Subject' type='text' className='txtBox'name="subject" value={this.state.subject} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>

<Button animated inverted color='blue'><Button.Content visible>Send</Button.Content>
        <Button.Content hidden>
          <Icon name='envelope'/>
        </Button.Content>
      </Button>
      <Button animated inverted color='red'><Button.Content visible>Discard</Button.Content>
        <Button.Content hidden>
       <Icon name='remove circle'/>
      </Button.Content>
      </Button>
      </Form>
      </Modal.Content>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    sentItem: state.sentMessage
  }
}
const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    sentBox: (sentMessage) => {
      dispatch(storeActions.sentBox(sentMessage))
    },
  }
};
// connect to store
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchToProps
)(Compose);
```

In redux foldder, reducer file:

```
import actions from './actions';

const initialState = {

sentMessage: []

}

const emailReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.SENT_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        sentMessage: state.sentMessage.concat(action.payload)
      };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }


  export default emailReducer;
```

In Action file:

```
const actions = {
    SENT_MESSAGE: "SENT_MESSAGE",

}
export default actions;
```

In storeActions.js:

```
import actions from './actions';

export function sentBox(sentMessage) {
    return function(dispatch) {
      dispatch({ type: actions.SENT_MESSAGE, payload: sentMessage });
  };
  }
```

Second Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {Grid, Input} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import * as storeActions from "../redux/storeActions";
class SentItem extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Grid.Row className="row message" >
            <Grid.Column width={1} className="myCheckbox">
            <Input type="checkbox"/>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={2} >
            <i className="star fa fa-star"></i>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={12}> sentMessage {this.props.sentMessage.map(msg => JSON.stringify(msg) )} 
            </Grid.Column>       
            </Grid.Row>

        );
    }
}




function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      sentMessage: state.sentMessage
    };
  }

  const dispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {

        sentBox: () => {
            dispatch(storeActions.sentBox())
          },
    }}



    // connect to store
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatchToProps
  )(SentItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that has to be improved:-

1) You don't need to bind function in constructor(`this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);` - this line could be removed) if you are already using arrow function.

2) You should be calling `this.props.sentBox(sentItem)` at the end of `handleSubmit` function to dispatch action with payload as `sentItem`.

3) `changeHandler` function should be corrected, otherwise correct state will not be populated for different inputs.

```
changeHandler = ({target}) => {
   const name = target.name;
   const value = target.value;
   this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

Let us know any error you are facing after these corrections.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Good to know that.

Comment: Awesome, i really appreciate it. I'm working on the above code from 5 days onwards but unable to sent object to another component.. Now it is working perfectly

Comment: How to display the content of the message. I mean the inputs which i'm entering in the field.. need to get displayed in the second component? Could you please help me in this?

Comment: Are you able to get value inside `this.props.sentMessage` in second component?

Comment: if i run the above code then i'm getting error in this way :  **Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.** but when i merge these components with few components then it is running successfully

Comment: Your code depicts that your are using redux thunk. You need to add `redux-thunk` library and its configuration. use this [link](https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3) to configure thunk if not already done so.

Comment: Now i could see the object. But we i merge with the remaining components, i'm unable to see the details @tarzen chugh